# Вывод в консоль Fortran 66 (IV)

Tags: консоль, fortran

1) Дайте пример кода, чтобы вывести сообщение в консоль по спецификации Fortran 66, не сохраняя в переменных строку, а сразу оператор вывода со строкой.
Пример на языке С#:

```
Console.WriteLine("Программист Программисту Программист");
```

2) Подскажите параметры чтения, чтобы не закрывал консоль, а ждал ввода любого символа обязательно Fortran66 он же FortranIV.
пример на языке С#:

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

Спасибо. 
Работает!Но не забывайте, что там без наворотов доступно ток латиница А-Z

```
program second

WRITE(*,10)
10    FORMAT('Программист Программисту Программист')
READ(*,20) 
20 FORMAT(//) 
end program second
```

Comment: можно используя только латиницу A-Z.

Comment: http://www.math-cs.gordon.edu/courses/cs323/FORTRAN/fortran.html читайте на здоровье. Позвольте спросить, а чем вас не устроил Fortran 77 или 92? и почему Fortran? Я ни чего не имею против этого языка, просто интересно?

Comment: такие рамки задачи, что бы больше озадачен был xD на самом деле сакральный смысл в том(наверное), что спецификация fortran66 поддерживается на всех последующих версиях, а в обратную сторону не работает, а на нём(fortran66) море кода обещают.

Comment: спецификация f77 сильно отличается от f66 по ряду моментов, не говоря уже о f90-95. f66 вроде как первый стандартизованный http://www.eah-jena.de/~kleine/history/languages/ansi-x3dot9-1966-Fortran66.pdf, ну да ладно, иногда полезно и палеонтологией заниматься =)

Comment: по поводу моря кода не врут, библиотеки мат. моделей действительно огромны и большая часть не портирована на современные языки

Comment: вроде
`READ(*,20) I 
    20 FORMAT(A1)  или 
         READ(*,20)
    20 FORMAT(//)`

Comment: В фортране 4 оператор должен начинаться с 7-й позиции, первые 5 позиций для метки, потом признак переноса строки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
      WRITE(*,10)
10    FORMAT('Программист Программисту Программист')
```

Comment: первую звездочку может не съесть, там указывается номер устройства или файла, во всех примерах стоит 6, возможно 6 - консоль, компилятора под руками нет чтобы проверить =)

Comment: @rdorn да, были разные диалекты, кодировка не знаю какая, но кириллица у нас была, а строковые значения записывали как-то в целые переменные

Comment: у нас в институте стояла дековская альфа на которой много древностей крутилось, но мы работали с ней по телнету и на 77 фортране =) там уже можно было просто писать `WRITE(*,*) 'Output text'`